# Data of workflow disappeared unexpectedly in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

My flow works correctly but after one hour data of flow becomes disappeared. I've reduced and increased Heap size memory from 100mb until 8g it did not work, my cpu usage increased until 500% and then data of my flow is disappeared.I mean In/out of all processors became zero,I attached my flow. does anybody have a solution?

my system config:
macOs high sierra
processor 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
memory 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

this is log of my flow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGtJX.png)

this is my flow after losing data and deleting content 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K85kn.png)

Comment: what does it mean `flow dies`? any errors in the log? why you are reducing memory instead of increasing? please edit your question and add details.

Comment: @daggett Thanks for your response, I edited my question. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Just to check off the obvious: Are you sure your flow is not simply empty? (the in-out statistics are only valid for some time). -- Also note that you still seem to have something in the bottom of your flow.--- A way to disprove my assumption is to see something in the queue before a processor, and then seeing it picked up while the statistics go to zero very soon after.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I'm sure my flow is not empty at first, but after a while my flow becomes empty. When my queue is empty how can I see something in it?

Comment: @zahraeslami, `all processors became zero` - it's normal if nifi finished processing all the data. the statistics on queues and processors is available only for the last 5 minutes. so, if your nifi do nothing during last 5 minutes - all stats will be zero.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this explanation of these basic concepts clears up the confusion.

## About NiFi

NiFi is a flow management tool, you can have processors to ingest, process and egest data.

Typically a message comes in, and goes out once NiFi is done with it.

## About statistics

Each processor will keep track of incoming and outgoing messages. These messages are tracked for a while on the processor, and then 'forgotten'. I believe the time period is 5 minutes.

## About queues

You can inspect a queue to see the messages in it, if there are no messages you cannot inspect them of course. You might be interested in the provenance.

## About provenance

You can check the provenance of a message in the queue to see how it developed (content, timestamps) as it passed the processors. I have personally worked mostly with NiFi in HDF, so I'm not sure if this option is available when you run NiFi without a platform around it.

## Detecting problems in NiFi

Of course there may be exceptions, but if NiFi is unable to pick up messages, I would expect them to get stuck in a queue. And if NiFi is processing them but failing, you would expect red squares to start appearing in the UI.

So usually it is quite easy to tell if something is going wrong in NiFi.

Comment: Yes, data provenance is a native feature in Apache NiFi, so it does not require any external platform to be present and available.